ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestsTransport' from 'azure.core.pipeline.transport' import RequestsTransport, HttpTransport
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\queue\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._queue_client import QueueClient
  File "C:\Users\AZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\queue\_queue_client.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ._shared.base_client import StorageAccountHostsMixin, parse_connection_str, parse_query
  File "C:\Users\AZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\queue\_shared\base_client.py", line 26, in <module>
    from azure.core.pipeline.transport import RequestsTransport, HttpTransport
ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestsTransport' from 'azure.core.pipeline.transport' (C:\Users\AZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1

I have azure-core==1.31.0,azure-storage-blob==12.19.0
azure-storage-queue==12.1.6
I have verified in the base_client.py file it's importing "from azure.core.pipeline.transport import RequestsTransport, HttpTransport". Still its failing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Reinstall Azure-Core module with version that includes RequestsTransport to ensure compatibility (or) create a new virtual environment and reinstall latest versions all the required modules.
The file names in your project should not match with the module names you are using. In such cases, rename the file fixes the issue.
I have created a Python Azure function and installed below modules.
Requirements.txt:

Install the latest version of the modules.

azure-functions
azure-core
azure-storage-blob
azure-storage-queue

Sample Code:
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  logging

from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueClient
from  azure.core.exceptions  import  AzureError

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        blob_data = req.get_body() 
        blob_name = "sample-blob.txt"
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(blob_data, overwrite=True)

        logging.info(f"Blob uploaded successfully: {blob_name}")

        message = "New blob uploaded: " + blob_name
        queue_client.send_message(message)
        logging.info(f"Message sent to queue: {message}")

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Blob uploaded and message sent: {message}", status_code=200)

    except AzureError as e:
        logging.error(f"Azure Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Azure error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

Output:
[2024-11-05T08:32:35.531Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=29a710d8-7306-4932-b97f-80aa0dfd01f1)
[2024-11-05T08:32:35.643Z] Request URL: 'https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/container1/sample-blob.txt'
Request method: 'PUT'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Length': '0'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.19.0 Python/3.11.9 (Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '8239b614-9b50-11ef-b49d-98fa9b0d1c80'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
[2024-11-05T08:32:37.190Z] Response status: 201
Response headers:
    'Content-Length': '0'
    'Content-MD5': 'REDACTED'
    'Last-Modified': 'Tue, 05 Nov 2024 08:32:36 GMT'
    'ETag': '"0x8DCFD7466B2CBD9"'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '2bb7857f-201e-005b-215d-2f79f7000000'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '8239b614-9b50-11ef-b49d-98fa9b0d1c80'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-content-crc64': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Tue, 05 Nov 2024 08:32:35 GMT'
[2024-11-05T08:32:37.196Z] Blob uploaded successfully: sample-blob.txt
[2024-11-05T08:32:37.196Z] Request URL: 'https://storage.queue.core.windows.net/queue1/messages'
Request method: 'POST'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'Content-Length': '129'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-queue/12.1.6 Python/3.11.9 (Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '832749a2-9b50-11ef-a0bc-98fa9b0d1c80'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
A body is sent with the request
[2024-11-05T08:32:39.035Z] Response status: 201
Response headers:
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '4b284df6-5003-0076-655d-2ffa37000000'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Tue, 05 Nov 2024 08:32:37 GMT'
[2024-11-05T08:32:39.046Z] Message sent to queue: New blob uploaded: sample-blob.txt
[2024-11-05T08:32:39.314Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=29a710d8-7306-4932-b97f-80aa0dfd01f1, Duration=3796ms)

Container:

Queue:

